# Proof that $gcd(n, p-1) > 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $F(n) = \underbrace{111..11}_{n \text{times}}$

Proof that if $p|F(n)$ then $gcd(n, p-1) > 1$

(p - prime and $p>3$)

### My approach

If $n$ is even it is true because $p-1$ is even too so 
$$gcd(n, p-1) \ge 2 > 1 $$

But I completely don't know how to start with odd numbers...

### Example

$n=5$
$F(n) = 11111 = 271\cdot 41$
$gcd(5,270) > 0$
$gcd(5,40) > 0$

### Update:

From answer I know that
$$ 10^{n}\equiv 10^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p $$
so
$$gcd(n,p-1) = gcd(log_{10}(pk+1), log_{10}(pt+1)) \text{ for some k,t} $$
I am trying to show that it implies thesis...

Answer (score 5):

$9F(n)=10^n-1$, so if $p\mid F(n)$ then $10^n\equiv 1\pmod p$, that is, $n$ is a multiple of the order of $10$ in $\Bbb Z_p^\times$, which is a non trivial divisor of $p-1$.

Comment: Just to put it in other words: $10^{n}\equiv 10^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ So, $ord_p(10)$ divides $(n,p-1)$.

Comment: what is $ord_p(10)$? I didn't have orders and groups on my lecture :(

Comment: and how you got  $10^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$?

Comment: @Witalij If $p$ is neither $2$ or $5$, then $10^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ due to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Can it be solved without informations about $ord_p(10)$?